# example of risk neutral or risk loving utility function

Tags: utility, risk, risk-aversion

i"m looking for an example of either risk loving or risk neutral utility function. what i mean is like for risk averse, we have the HARA utility function. is there a utility function that exhibit risk neutral individual like HARA exhibit risk averse individual? thank you very much for the help.

edit: i also need the risk loving example guys, thank you so much for the one who have answered the risk neutral example

Comment: $u(x_1, ...., x_n) = \sum x_i$

Comment: There really is only one risk-neutral utility function: $u(x)=x$. More generally, you can have $u(x)=\alpha x+\beta$ with $\alpha>0$, but this is really the same utility function; the preferences over lotteries are the same.

Comment: what about the risk loving one? do you happen to know any function that shows utility of a risk loving individual? thank you

Comment: Any convex increasing function will do.

Comment: Thank you so much